# Row specific action in child component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have two aura components, parent and a child. They are similar to https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/08/09/add-delete-rows-dynamic/

Parent Component looks something like this:

```
<aura:component >
    <!--Table Part-->
    <table >
        <thead>     
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <!--Iterate the child Component to display Table rows 
            by passing the List Item Index to track the Every child Component 
            and pass each List sobject Instance -->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.sobjectList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                <c:childComponent sobjInstance="{!item}" rowIndex="{!index}" />
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

And the child component:

```
<aura:component>

    <!-- Aura Attribute for store single BookingCaptureLine__c Instance
    And Store Index of Particular Instance -->
    <aura:attribute name="sobjectInstance" type="sobject"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowIndex" type="String"/>

    <!-- Register 2 Lightning Event for handle add or Delete rows on Parent Component-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="DeleteRowEvt" type="c:DeleteRowEvt"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="AddRowEvt" type="c:AddNewRowEvt"/>

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.sobjectInstance.NumberField__c}" action="{!c.callOnChange}"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.sobjectInstance.Lookup_Field__c}" action="{!c.callOnChange}"/>

    <!-- Table Row -->
    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
        <th data-label="Add/Remove">
           <div class="slds-truncate" title="Add/Remove">
                <!-- conditionally Display Add or Delete Icons
                    if rowIndex is 0 then show Add New Row Icon else show delete Icon
                -->
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.rowIndex == 0}">
                    <a onclick="{!c.AddNewRow}">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="action:new" size="xx-small" alternativeText="add"/>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Add Icon</span>
                    </a>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <a onclick="{!c.removeRow}">
                            <lightning:icon variant="error" iconName="action:delete" size="xx-small" alternativeText="icon"/>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete Icon</span>
                        </a>
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </div>
        </th>
        <td data-label="Row No">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Row No">
                {!v.rowIndex + 1}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="{!$ObjectType.sobject.fields.NumberField__c.Label}">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!$ObjectType.sobject.fields.NumberField__c.Label}">
                <force:inputField class="slds-input" value="{!v.sobjectInstance.NumberField__c}" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="{!$ObjectType.sobject.fields.Lookup_Field__c.Label}">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!$ObjectType.sobject.fields.Lookup_Field__c.Label}">
                <force:inputField class="slds-input" value="{!v.sobjectInstance.Lookup_Field__c}"/>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
</aura:component>
```

So when I click the Add Icon, it registers the event and then calls the parent methods.

However, it also calls the **callOnChange** action for all the old rows however **callOnChange** should be called *only when the value of lookup field or number field on a particular row is changed* and not when a new row is added or deleted.

So, if there are existing **n** rows then **callOnChange** is called **2*n** times before adding a row, same goes when I click the remove icon to remove a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.sobjectList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
    <c:childComponent sobjInstance="{!item}" rowIndex="{!index}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

Changed

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.sobjectList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
    <c:childComponent sobjInstance="{#item}" rowIndex="{!index}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

I used the **{#expression} (Unbound Expressions)** instead of **{!expression} (Bound Expressions)**

Further reading here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm